# Revolut merchant API - payment failed

Tags: vue.js

Has anyone worked with Revolut payment API? Documentation is quite clear, I do everything accordingly, and still I receive `code: 2007` with server response `502` - sadly, there is no code book anywhere to check its meaning. Code making request is quite straighforward - after receiving `public_id` from the server, I do the following.

```js
RevolutCheckout(public_id).then((instance) => {
  instance.payWithPopup({
    onSuccess: () => this.$emit("success"),
    onError(message) {
      alert(message);
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that, despite documentation claiming otherwise in tutorial sections, `name` field is actually required. After including it everything works as expected:

```js
RevolutCheckout(public_id).then((instance) => {
  instance.payWithPopup({
    name: this.order.name,
    onSuccess: () => this.$emit("success"),
    onError(message) {
      alert(message);
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Correct, I had the same problem, support told me the same. Alerted the Revolut support about that documentation issue.

Answer (score 0):

are you having any success with this?. I had it initially failing like you describe and then working for some time in production environment with real cards, and now it says transaction failed again. It still registers the payment attempt in the order though.